# How can I get a localized version of a YUI 3 or AlloyUI component?

Tags: yui, yui3, alloy-ui

As an example, how could I render an AlloyUI scheduler which has the days in Japanese rather than English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a localized version of a YUI 3 component you must use the YUI config object's `lang` property. When specifying a YUI sandbox, pass it the language code(s) which you want the component(s) to be localized for:

```
YUI({ lang : 'ja-JP' }).use( // your code here...
```

Here is a specific example with the AlloyUI scheduler:

```
YUI({ lang : 'ja-JP' }).use('aui-scheduler', function(Y) {
    new Y.Scheduler({
        boundingBox: '#myScheduler',
        items: [],
        render: true,
        views: [new Y.SchedulerWeekView()]
    });
});
```

You may also need to internationalize the `strings` attribute of your components yourself. For example, the `Scheduler` has many strings that are not internationalized by changing the `YUI` `lang` attribute. If you want to fully internationalize it, [you'll need to translate each string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781072/how-to-localize-the-alloyui-scheduler-component/46439216#46439216).

For more information see the [YUI Internationalization documentation](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/intl/) (specifically the [Requesting Preferred Languages section](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/intl/#prefLang)).