# How to localize the alloyui scheduler component?

Tags: yui3, alloy-ui

I am trying to fully localize the alloyui scheduler in French.
Following this article: [How can I get a localized version of a YUI 3 or AlloyUI component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151139) the job is almost done.
However I am still missing tips for two things:
- I need the time format in the left column to be changed from 1-12am/pm to 1-24
- I don't succeed to localize the "All day" term in the left top corner (or at least a way to hide it).

Any help will be welcome

Comment: The term "Show more" when events are grouped in the same day cell also remains in English. Any tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change to a 24 hour clock, you need to set the [`isoTime` attribute](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerView.html#attr_isoTime) to `true` for each `SchedulerView` subclass that you are using.

To internationalize the strings, you need to set the `strings` attribute of [`Scheduler`](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Scheduler.html), [`SchedulerDayView`](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerDayView.html) [`SchedulerWeekView`](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerWeekView.html), [`SchedulerMonthView`](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerMonthView.html), [`SchedulerAgendaView`](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerAgendaView.html), and [`SchedulerEventRecorder`](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerEventRecorder.html) as well as setting [`YUI`'s `lang` attribute](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/config.html#property_lang) to the locale of your choice. For example, I've used [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com)* to internationalize the `Scheduler` below for Spanish users:

```
YUI({lang: 'es-ES'}).use('aui-scheduler', function (Y) {
    var es_ES_strings_allDay = { allDay: 'todo el dia' };
    new Y.Scheduler({
        render: true,
        // https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Scheduler.html#attr_strings
        // https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/3.0.3-deprecated.65/src/aui-scheduler/js/aui-scheduler-base.js#L606-L622
        strings: {
            agenda: 'agenda',
            day: 'día',
            month: 'mes',
            today: 'hoy',
            week: 'semana',
            year: 'año'
        },
        views: [
            // https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerDayView.html#attr_strings
            // https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/3.0.3-deprecated.65/src/aui-scheduler/js/aui-scheduler-view-day.js#L363-L373
            new Y.SchedulerDayView({
                isoTime: true,
                strings: es_ES_strings_allDay
            }),
            // https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerWeekView.html#attr_strings
            // SchedulerWeekView extends SchedulerDayView: https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/3.0.3-deprecated.65/src/aui-scheduler/js/aui-scheduler-view-week.js#L19
            new Y.SchedulerWeekView({
                isoTime: true,
                strings: es_ES_strings_allDay
            }),
            // https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerMonthView.html#attr_strings
            // https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/3.0.3-deprecated.65/src/aui-scheduler/js/aui-scheduler-view-week.js#L19
            new Y.SchedulerMonthView({
                isoTime: true,
                strings: {
                    showMore: 'mostrar {0} más',
                    close: 'cerrar'
                }
            }),
            // https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerAgendaView.html#attr_strings
            // https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/3.0.3-deprecated.65/src/aui-scheduler/js/aui-scheduler-view-week.js#L19
            new Y.SchedulerAgendaView({
                isoTime: true,
                strings: {
                    noEvents: 'No hay eventos futuros'
                }
            })
        ],
        // https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerEventRecorder.html#attr_strings
        // https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/3.0.3-deprecated.65/src/aui-scheduler/js/aui-scheduler-view-week.js#L19
        eventRecorder: new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder({
            strings: {
                'delete': 'borrar',
                'description-hint': 'descripción insinuación',
                cancel: 'cancelar',
                description: 'descripción',
                edit: 'editar',
                save: 'salvar',
                when: 'cuando'
            }
        })
    });
});
```

* I don't recommend using Google Translate to internationalize a production application since there are many nuances to internationalization that a machine translation will miss.